# Pinch Zoom Gesture android

Tags: android

[The android developer page](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/gestures.html) lists that pinch open and pinch close are supported  by android API.But I could not find the appropriate API / method which does that. Most of the posts suggest that the native pinch is not available.

Is the native pinch and zoom available for android 4.1 + applications? If so which is the API?

(Edit : I am a newbie to Android and any pointers or resources on how to zoom individual elements in a canvas, like a rectangle, would be so valuable to me. Thanks)

Comment: You may want to start at [ScaleGestureDector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ScaleGestureDetector.html)

Answer (score 1):

Check this out for gesture on activity or canvas for moving, scaling and rotation:
http://code.almeros.com/android-multitouch-gesture-detectors#.Udcq_z789cR

Comment: Poor answer, just link.

Comment: No offense, if you have better solution please provide constructive answer too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ScaleGestureDetector](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ScaleGestureDetector) to detect zoom in/out by two-finger touch, or also double-tap and move up/down which is now standard on Android (e.g. used in Google Maps).

ScaleGestureDetector gives you screen point around which you can zoom, and scale change as you move fingers on screen.

You're not limited to zooming, you can also do other actions resulting from the scale gesture.